# Executing UPDATE query in node.js mysql not working

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am new to node.js (and mysql in combination with that) and trying to update my database based on request parameter and a request body. My beginning of the file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'm3ttulat0r',
    debug: true
});
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

My request looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/mettmeister/1
```

The request body looks like this:

```
{
  "mettmeister": "Jonas"
}
```

The connection to the database is successful. Then I have the following code:

```
app.post('/mettmeister/:mettwochId', function(req, res) {

    var mettmeister = req.body.mettmeister;
    var mettwochId = req.params.mettwochId;
    var query = 'UPDATE mettwoch SET mettmeister = "'+ mettmeister +'" WHERE mettwoch_id = "'+ mettwochId +'"';

    console.log(mettmeister, mettwochId);

    connection.query(query, function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            res.status(201);
        } else {
            res.status(500);
        }
    });

});
```

`console.log(mettmeister, mettwochId);` returns `Jonas 1` which is fine.

The problem is that it sends the request and the server gets the message according to the log but nothing happens. The server "stops" at executing the query apparently.

I have debugging turned on and the query looks fine.

```
--> ComQueryPacket
{ command: 3,
  sql: 'UPDATE mettwoch SET mettmeister = "Jonas" WHERE mettwoch_id = "1"' }
```

If I execute the query manually in my database, it works.. I am really happy for any help. Thank you! :)

Comment: When the server doesn't respond, does the value in DB get updated?

Comment: Is the `mettwoch_id` an INT? If so, try removing quotes: `mettwoch_id = 1`

Comment: You should escape your variables using in sql because your code may be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @Mr.Web It is but executing it manually works fine.

Comment: @jonicious, I see...

Comment: what is the dataType of the coloum mettwoch_id in your db?

Comment: @satishrajak An INT but executing it manually works fine.

Comment: @jonicious Do `console.log(err);`

Comment: @jcubic ``'UPDATE mettwoch SET mettmeister = ' + connection.escape(mettmeister) + 'WHERE mettwoch_id = ' + connection.escape(mettwochId);`` like described [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) appears to not working. The query then looks like this: ``UPDATE mettwoch SET mettmeister = \'Jonas\'WHERE mettwoch_id = \'1\'``

Comment: @thefourtheye ``null``

Comment: @jonicious And you are sure that DB is not updated, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye You can't imagine how bad I feel right now..

Comment: @thefourtheye But ``if (!err)`` should be executed nevertheless am I right?

Comment: @jonicious Sorry, I didn't mean to make you feel bad. But most of the times, we, developers, overlook small things. That is why I want you to make sure whether the DB got updated or not.

Comment: @jonicious It does get executed.

Comment: Yes, it does.  ``if (!err) {
            console.log("successful");
            res.status(201);
        } else {
            res.status(500);
        }``

Comment: ``console.log("successful")`` is executed but setting the status of the response seems to not working..

Comment: Having the same problem, but if I set a breakpoint in mysql Connection.js at line 206, print out query.sql, and then paste it into MySQL Workbench and execute it it works perfectly. It seems like the problems is deeper down in the mysql code after the request is enqueued as I never seem to get a response from mysql.

Answer (score 4):

Use update query like this

```
connection.query('UPDATE mettwoch SET ? WHERE ?', [{ mettmeister: mettmeister }, { mettwoch_id: mettwochId }])
```

Comment: My code now looks like this:  ``connection.query('UPDATE mettwoch SET ? WHERE ?', [{ mettmeister: mettmeister }, { mettwoch_id: mettwochId }], function(err) {
        console.log(err);

        if (!err) {
            res.status(201);
        } else {
            res.status(500);
        }
    });``

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am stupid. Sorry guys :(

I did the following

```
res.status(201);
```

Actually you have to finish the request like this:

```
res.status(201).end();
```

Comment: That is correct, but you have been telling that DB is also not getting updated.

Comment: @thefourtheye Overlooking the obvious things.. :/ I am so sorry :(

Comment: If I am not mistaken, shorter way -- `sendStatus`.